# Loading all files within a directory

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I've made this little function which I'm wanting to call all the files within a directory.

I don't think the `glob() == false` would work though. I'm new to this function so not aware of all possibilities and I find the php.net references unhelpful to some extent.

My desired outcome is if glob() fails to load any files an array of the files can be loaded via `require_once()` separately for each file. This would just be more of a fallback, unless there is an easier more efficient option.

```
if(glob() == false) { echo "0 files found" } else {
    foreach( glob(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/postypes/*.php') as $path )
        require_once( $path );
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using an autoloader? The files in question would only be loaded as and when they are needed with no manual requires or includes necessary

Comment: @TomJNowell Please consider adding an answer for that

Comment: I could but while interesting/useful to the asker, it wouldn't actually answer the question, perhaps a new question.. once I've had a cup of tea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Loading files from a directory - the historical way

The [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.glob.php) function has three possible return values:

- Array( filenames ) `=>` success
- Array() empty `=>` nothing found
- `FALSE` `=>` Error

So the correct check would be

```
$files = glob( sprintf( 
    '%s/postypes/*.php',
    get_stylesheet_directory()
) );
if ( empty( $files )
{
    _e( 'No PHP files found', 'your-textdomain' );
}
elseif ( ! $files )
{
    _e( 'Shrug! There went something terribly wrong!', 'your-textdomain' );
}
else
{
    foreach ( $files as $file )
        include_once $file;
}
```

…buuuut…

### The current days way to fetch & load files - PHP 5.3+

Since we are already reaching the end of life of PHP 5.3 support, we can assume that someone at least got PHP 5.3.x installed and therefore has the *SPL* (Standard PHP Library) extension installed - even Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Long term support) has 5.3 packaged / Ubuntu current is v14. Even when you are running PHP 5.2.x, the *SPL* has to be forcefully turned *off*.

And the SPL ships with the [`DirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.directoryiterator.php). So a good setup to load files would look like this:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator( sprintf( 
    '%s/postypes/*.php',
    get_stylesheet_directory()
) );

$it->rewind();
foreach ( $it as $fileInfo )
{
    if ( $fileInfo->isDot() )
        continue;

    include_once $fileInfo->getFileName();
}
```

### Extended ...

(Edit) For some reason, I mixed the `DirectoryIterator` with the `FilesystemIterator`. Of course you should use the later for PHP 5.3 as the later one is a follow up development of the first one.

The nice thing is, that the `FilesystemIterator` as well as the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` has FLAGS, so you can - instead of using the `isDot()` method - simply set a flag:

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator( __DIR__.'/assets', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( __DIR__.'/assets', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
```

Here's a different example with a little more detailed checks:

```
# Assume we got this in the functions.php file of a theme
# and we want to load PHP vendor files.
$it = new FilesystemIterator(
    __DIR__.'/vendor/*.php',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
);

$it->rewind();
while ( $it->valid() )
{
    if (
        $it->isReadable()
        AND $it->isFile()
        AND $it->current() instanceof \SplFileInfo
    )
        include_once $it->current()->getFilename()

    $it->next();
}
```

You could as well search through different directories using the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and adding your pattern there. Make sure to use a max depth to not overdo it with a search.

What you could do as well, is using a [`NoRewindIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.norewinditerator.php), which takes an `Iterator` or something else that `implements Traversable` and loops over it. This way you can make sure that you won't iterator over a single file more than once.

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    __DIR__.'/vendor/*.php',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO
);
$it->rewind();
$files = new NoRewindIterator( $it );
$files->rewind();
foreach ( $files as $file )
    # ...
```

but that may just be too much.

Comment: Great awnser Kaiser. I understand this and nice to see an OOP option so DirectoryIterator is a new class shopped with SPL? also is there a way to load multiple directories applying an array of values within the sprintf?

Comment: @Dannyw24 see update